# Akkusativ / Dativ mit vorgestellter Präposition

Tags: grammatical-case, accusative

In einem Satz wie

> Ich gehe jeden Sonntag in die Schule.

ist *die Schule* das Akkusativobjekt? Theoretisch kann ich ja fragen: »Wen oder was?«, aber in Sätzen wie

> Peter bringt den Jungen in die Schule.

ist das Akkusativobjekt nicht *in die Schule*, sondern *den Jungen*.

Deswegen wollte ich fragen, welcher Regel ich bei einfach Aufgaben, wie: »Unterstreiche farbig Nominativ, Genitiv, Dativ und Akkusativ«, folgen kann.

Comment: Nein, **in die Schule** ist ein Präpositionalobjekt. Allerdings kann die Präposition *in* wie eben hier mit dem Fall Akkusativ stehen.

Comment: Akkusative kommen nicht nur im Akkusativobjekt vor. Das Akkusativobjekt ist zwar das typische Vorkommen eines Akkusativs, aber längst nicht das einzige. Dasselbe gilt auch für die anderen Kasus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die beiden Wörter *»die Schule«* sind zwar eine Nominalgruppe die im Akkusativ steht, aber diese Gruppe steht dort zusammen mit einer Präposition. Erst der Teil

> in die Schule

ist ein vollständiges Satzglied. Da es mit einer Präposition beginnt, ist es entweder ein Präpositionalobjekt oder eine adverbiale Bestimmung (beide sehen auf den ersten Blick recht ähnlich aus).

Wie du richtig erkannt hast, kann man nach *»die Schule«* nicht mit *»wen oder was«* fragen, daher können diese beiden Wörter zusammen kein Akkusativobjekt sein.

Aber du kannst nach *»**in** die Schule«* mit »wohin« fragen:

> 1. Ich gehe jeden Sonntag **wohin?** <sub>(Satzglieder in derselben Reihenfolge wie im ursprünglichen Satz)</sub>
> 2. **Wohin** gehe ich jeden Sonntag? <sub>(Fragewort auf Position 1 verschoben)</sub>

Antwort:

> 1. Ich gehe jeden Sonntag **in die Schule.**
> 2. **In die Schule** gehe ich jeden Sonntag.

Wenn in der Frage die Präposition des zu bestimmenden Satzteiles enthalten ist (entweder allein oder als Teil des Frageworts), handelt es sich um ein Präpositionalobjekt. Das ist hier der Fall: Im Wort *woh**in*** ist die Präposition **in** enthalten.
<sub>(Das Fragewort setzt sich aus *wo* und *in* zusammen, das *h* ist so etwas wie ein Fugenlaut, der mit *in* das Wort *hin* ergibt, was eine Richtung anzeigt. Ähnliches gilt für das *r* in *worin*, hier ist *rin* das Signal, dass nicht nach einer Richtung, sondern nach einem Ort gefragt wird)</sub>

Gegenbeispiel:

> Ich bin jeden Sonntag **in der Schule.**

Hier lautet die Frage: **wo?**

> Frage: **Wo** bin ich jeden Sonntag?
>   Antwort: Ich bin jeden Sonntag **in der Schule.**

Die Präposition *»in«* kommt in der Frage nicht vor. Daher ist *»in der Schule«* kein Präpositionalobjekt. Es ist eine *adverbiale Bestimmung*

Übrigens:

> **Wann** gehe ich in die Schule?
>   Ich gehe **jeden Sonntag** in die Schule.

Die Nominalgruppe *»jeden Sonntag«* ist auch eine adverbiale Bestimmung (nämlich eine zeitliche adverbialer Bestimmung), die auch im Akkusativ steht. Trotzdem ist sie kein Akkusativobjekt, denn du kannst in diesem Satz nicht mit *»wen oder was«* nach »*jeden Sonntag«* fragen. Dieselbe Nominalgruppe kann aber in einem anderen Satz durchaus ein Akkusativobjekt sein:

> Harald muss von Montag bis Samstag arbeiten. Nur am Sonntag hat er seine Ruhe. Daher liebt Harald **jeden Sonntag.**
>   **Wen oder was** liebt Harald? - Er liebt **jeden Sonntag.**

---

Zurück zu deiner Aufgabenstellung:

Wenn die Aufgabe lautet: »Unterstreiche farbig Nominativ, Genitiv, Dativ und Akkusativ«, dann kannst du *»jeden Sonntag«* und *»die Schule* ohne weiteres mit der Akkusativ-Farbe unterstreichen. Denn in der Aufgabenstellung wird ja nicht nach Objekten gefragt, sondern nach allem, was im Akkusativ steht.

Comment: sehr ausführliche und besonders differenzierte Erklärung, danke !